# MySQL query for checking event conflict

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Currently I making a school community site and I got a problem in a part were the administrator post a new event he/she wants check if the event start date and time has no conflict also end date and time before saving it on the database. I tried many queries still i fail to get the exact sql.

I'm using MySQL Server 5 and PHP 5.3. Can any one help me on how to query on the table i mean the right sql string.

Heres the table fields:

- event_id => int,
- event_type => enum('school','department'),
- event_title=> text,
- event_details=> longtext,
- event_start=> datetime,
- event_end=> datetime,
- event_added_by=> int,
- event_modified_on=> datetime,

Here is what i have right now:

```
 SELECT *, time(event_start) as start_time, time(event_end) as end_time
 FROM `tbl_events` WHERE ((date(event_start) between '2011-12-9' and
 '2011-12-15') AND (time(event_start) between '00:00:00' and
 '01:00:00')) OR ((date(event_end) between '2011-12-9' and
 '2011-12-15') AND
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have four things to look for that indicate a conflict:

1. an existing event starts before your event starts and ends after your event ends (your event is inside the existing event)
2. an existing event starts before your event starts and ends after your event starts (overlap the beginning of the new event)
3. an existing event starts before your event ends and ends after your event ends (overlap the end of the new event)
4. an existing event starts after your event starts and ends before your event ends (the existing event is inside the new event)

By before and after, I mean at the same time or before/after (<= and >=).

Comment: You could slightly simplify this to 3 conditions: 1) any existing event starts during yours, 2) any existing event ends during yours, or 3) any existing event starts before and ends after yours.

Comment: How about in the problem if the admin add in between on that dates?

Comment: It's only two conditions. See the other answers

Comment: @michael667 You're absolutely right. +1. I was trying to remember some older code I wrote that has four criteria. I got it wrong though, one was to account for null end times (and the query was doing something a bit different). Looking at it now, after reading your answer, it's obvious it could be shorter. Always interesting how obvious things are After someone shows them to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two checks to do that need to be combined into one condition:

- an (existing) event starts before your event ends

  *and*
- it ends after your event starts.

If the query with such a condition returns rows, there's a conflict.

I'm assuming here that the end time is the time when the event ceases to be active (or functional or valid or whatever). That is, if an event's start time equals another event's end time, there's no conflict in there. However, if that *should* be considered a conflict in your case, replace the *before* and *after* above with *before or when* and *after or when* respectively.

Here's how it might look in a query:

```
…
WHERE event_start < @new_event_end
  AND event_end > @new_event_start
…
```

Or, if no `event_start` should match another event's `event_end`:

```
…
WHERE event_start <= @new_event_end
  AND event_end >= @new_event_start
…
```

(That is, simply replace strict inequalities with non-strict ones.)

Comment: How about using BETWEEN in the statement? Is that possible?

Comment: @naviciroel: If you meant using `BETWEEN` instead of `>=` or `<=` or both, then no, you can't do that here, because all four values are different. A start value is compared to an end value, and a different end value is compared to a different start value. When using `BETWEEN`, you have the same value compared to some start value and some end value. So it's a different thing.

Answer (score 1):

This allows also for open ends (modeled by end = null):

```
WHERE (event2.start < event1.end OR event1.end is null)
AND (event2.end > event1.start OR event2.end is null)
```

And take care whether using > or >= (respectively < or <=), this depends on your data and requirements.